# Question about held notes in piano musical notation

Tags: piano, notation, beginner

My knowledge of musical notation is extremely limited, so I'm sorry if this is a dumb question...

Could anyone tell me how the the below bar would look if the 3 triplet notes marked in red in the bass cleff were all held until the end of the bar?

If possible, please edit my image to show how it should be:

[image]

The pitch of the notes were chosen at random so just ignore that.

Comment: The proposed duplicate is a slightly different question, but the answers will apply to this question as well.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I had already looked at a few questions about this, but I'm still not completely sure how my above example with the triplet notes should look.

Comment: In the linked question, the lead answer's final image shows the simplest option for a triplet.

Comment: I still don't have clear exactly how my example would be.

Comment: The difference between this question and the linked one is that in this case, the sound is to stop at the end of the bar. I would replace the rest on the fourth beat with a quarter-note chord consisting of the three pitches. The three triplet notes would each be tied to one of these chord notes. That in itself would probably be clear enough, but if not, you can double the stems and change the note heads according to the linked answer.

Comment: Just to check, if you mean that you should hold the Bb, letting its sound sustain, while also adding an F and sustaining that, and then a B and sustaining that, and letting the *three-note chord* sustain for an additional beat... then see the proposed duplicate. If it's only the top B that you want to hold, you can simply tie it to a following quarter note.

Comment: This discussion has prompted me to add a more simple solution to the other thread.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you would notate this:
[image]

Comment: Correct, but I think we could do it without the clashing tie lines.

Comment: Also the final G is the right hand is in the wrong octave.  (But +1 all the same.)

Answer (score -1):

I think A below is the tidiest way of doing it.    But is it possible B would convey your intention?

I think there's some flats missing!   Remember, accidentals only apply to that note, in that octave, in that bar.

[image]

Comment: "The pitch of the notes were chosen at random so just ignore that." - OP.